# As a developer, how to hide the popup in Google Drive after user installs our app

Tags: google-drive-api

[image]

After user installs our Google Drive app, there will be a popup window (see the picture above). 
But we don't want to show this popup to users. What should we do?

===
According to your reply, we cannot hide the popup. So can we default to uncheck the option to make it the default app its file types? (see the highlighted checkbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't hide this popup -- sorry. It is for the user and not the developer. After all, Google Drive is a consumer product and Drive apps should enhance their experience.

Having said that, I am not sure it is a great user experience, popping up; and we will certainly review it and look for alternative ways to alert the user.

Comment: Could you check one more question for us? Thanks.